# Websphere "This method must be called from DataDirect DataStoreHelper"

Tags: websphere, helper, datastore

we are getting this error messagge "This method must be called from DataDirect DataStoreHelper." preceded by this warning code "DSRA0080E".

Basically we have to use the MSSQLDataStoreHelper but the error indicate that 
we have to use the DataDirect DataStoreHelper.

Does anybady know how to fix it?

Anyway this is the stack trace with the exception:

[30/05/11 11.06.35:468 CEST] 00000015 WSJdbcDataSou W   DSRA0080E: Data Store Adapter ha ricevuto un'eccezione. Vedere il messaggio di eccezione originale: Unable to determine the WebSphere default isolation level from the DataStoreHelper
Defaulting to READ COMMITTED.
com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.MSSQLDataStoreHelper@60fc60fc
com.ibm.ws.exception.WsException: DSRA7001E: This method must be called from DataDirect DataStoreHelper.

Thx
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the default isolation level.
Check how the dbconnection is done and add parameters for isolation level.

Comment: Hi, we have done it setting the property webSphereDefaultIsolationLevel with the value 4 for each datasource, what else should we do?